# Disable fox pro table trigger from c# (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, triggers, odbc, foxpro

I need to add a row to a fox pro table and before inserting the row I need to disable the trigger applied on the fox pro table  and enable it back after inserting the row.

Is there any way to disable fox pro trigger from c# .NET ?

Thank you for any hints regarding this.

Comment: Only thing i can found about that is a book :) May be it helps you.

https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=wKNfTHRNkLAC&pg=PA233&lpg=PA233&dq=disable+foxpro+trigger+from+c%23+.&source=bl&ots=_0dTkYVq1H&sig=ACfU3U1CBiskoa7DSJt68aeNCOUsJykaLA&hl=tr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwirpvPLndHpAhXswosKHfdWBHQQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=disable%20foxpro%20trigger%20from%20c%23%20.&f=false

Comment: As i wrote on my "COMMENT" this "MAY" helps him. May be not. 
I did not claim that this is the right solution for his problem. This is the reason why I wrote it as a "COMMENT" not an "ANSWER". I just want help. I did some search and found a book that offers a solution for "temporary disable fox pro trigger" problem. So he can decide to buy or not. That is a choice. https://imgur.com/a/9K4gwg9

Comment: @anilcemsimsek, that only shows how to do it in VFP, no? The question is how to do it with C#. And after all, to do it only in VFP you don't need to buy a book, press F1 and you have in there.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no direct way of doing that, even using ExecScript. Using ExecScript, you could run `delete trigger` code and it would return `true` without any errors as if it did it. But it doesn't remove the trigger, nor returns information that the trigger is still intact. Unfortunately, you can't even use ExecScript to bypass code that is otherwise not supported by the VFPOLEDB.

The only way you can do it, is to create a copy of the dbc (using VFP `modify database` - or C# low level if you are brave enough) and in that copy have the the same table definition without the trigger.

For example:

- Take a copy of your existing .dbc (.dct and .dcx)
- Modify table to remove the trigger (or do it in code:)

  ```
  Delete Trigger On ('yourTableName') For Insert
  ```
- Save this .dbc, .dct and .dcx under a different name.
- Restore existing .dbc, .dct, .dcx.
- When you need it you could replace the .dbc, .dct, .dcx files and then put back when done.

It is cumbersome but better than nothing.

Probably you would want to instead have an VFP executable that you can call with parameters and that does the insertion for you.